# Change Object Value using forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am trying to change the value of object from the array but, it's not work as expected. I tried following.

```js
const arrObj = [
  {
    "label": "test1",
    "value": 123,
    "type": "number",
    "field": {
      "label": "another",
      "description": "abcd"
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "test2",
    "value": 111,
    "type": "number"
  },
]

arrObj.forEach(obj => {
  obj = {...obj, ...obj.field}
  delete obj.field
})

console.log("after:", arrObj);
```

Also I found some solution that to use index but, it add index before the object.

```js
const arrObj = [
  {
    "label": "test1",
    "value": 123,
    "type": "number",
    "field": {
      "label": "abcd",
      "description": "abcd"
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "test2",
    "value": 111,
    "type": "number"
  }
]

arrObj.forEach((obj, index) => {
  obj[index] = {...obj, ...obj.field}
  delete obj.field
})

console.log("after:", arrObj);
```

How can I do with forEach?

Edit:

I want to remove the field object and assign/overwrite all the property outside.

Comment: It's not clear what result you want.

Comment: Which value do you want to change or delete?

Comment: forEach 3rd parameter is the original array so `forEach((obj,idx,origArr)` and access as `origArr[idx] = {...obj, ...obj.field}` and so on

Comment: @jarmod I edited question. I want to remove fields and take all property to outside.

Comment: @acarlstein  I edited question. I want to remove fields and take all property to outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` and assigning the result is probably a better way of doing this, but if you want to use `forEach`, you need to assign to the original array inside the loop:

```js
const arrObj = [
  {
    "label": "test1",
    "value": 123,
    "type": "number",
    "field": {
      "label": "another",
      "description": "abcd"
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "test2",
    "value": 111,
    "type": "number"
  },
]

arrObj.forEach(({ field, ...rest}, idx, orig) => {
  orig[idx] = { ...rest, ...field }
})

console.log(arrObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use map to change an array, but you may have a reason that you wish to modify the original.  You could just reassign arrObj to the output of the map.

```js
const arrObj = [
  {
    "label": "test1",
    "value": 123,
    "type": "number",
    "field": {
      "label": "another",
      "description": "abcd"
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "test2",
    "value": 111,
    "type": "number"
  },
]

const newArr = arrObj.map(( obj ) => {
 const {field, ...rest} = obj
 return {...field, ...rest}
})

console.log("after:", newArr);
```

Comment: for reassigning might need `let`

Comment: If the OP needs to reassign that would be the case, I didn't reassign in the example however.  Thanks for the clarity.